# Differentiating Between a Drupal Hook Implementation and a Regular Function

Tags: php, drupal, naming-conventions, hook, drupal-hooks

I have a couple of questions on Drupal coding conventions that I haven't been able to gleam from the docs or the code.

Outside of knowing the name of every hook in Drupal, is there a way to differentiate a function that *implements* a hook from a function that's just providing a bit of functionality for a hook?  Either something enforced via code or some convention?

Second, possibly related question.  After reviewing the core modules, I've noticed that some functions are named with a leading underscore

```
function _node_rankings(SelectQueryExtender $query) {
    ...
}
```

What meaning is attached to the underscore?  My assumption it's mimicking a "protected" convention, meaning that it should only be called from other functions in the `node.module` file; however, I couldn't find anything to confirm this.

I know about the [Coding Standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards), but they seem aimed at general PHP syntax, not conventions aimed at Drupal's internal systems.

Comment: Early in coding stardarts it was there, I assume they removed "underscore" convention as unusual...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question, if you look at the code of most modules, the comments above hook implementations will typically say:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_foo().
 */
```

After working with Drupal a while, you'll start to recognize the most common hooks.

Comment: +1 for the info. I've seen that, but it's now **always** there.  I'm looking for a deterministic way (which, to be fair, I don't think exists).

Comment: If you run the Coder module against another module, it will tell you which hook implementations are missing the documentation line described above: https://drupal.org/project/coder

Answer (score 3):

You're right, the underscore prefix in function names indicates that it should be treated as a private function, only being called by the module that declared it.

I don't know if this is in Drupal's official docs, but there are some posts on drupal.org confirming this (like [this](http://drupal.org/node/70335) or [this](http://drupal.org/node/866102)).

EDIT: and yes, it also works to avoid turning a "normal" function into a hook implementation (although you should try to not name functions after existing hooks).